# What is the java equivalent of time.clock from python?

Tags: java, python, drawing

I am trying to make a keyboard in java, that plays audio when a key is typed. When the key is typed, I want to highly the selected region of the keyboard when it is clicked in red. However this is not working, and I believe it is because of the refresh rate. I assume this because when I comment out the code dealing with the refresh it highlights fine, but the sound does not work right. 
How can I get the keyboard to refresh and highlight the pressed key every time a new key is pressed?

Currently I am using, this is only part of the code. The relevant part.

```
double KEYBOARD_REFRESH_DELAY = 0.01;
long start = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

if ((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) % 1000) - start > KEYBOARD_REFRESH_DELAY) {
    start = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    drawKeyboard(pressed);
    StdDraw.show(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by codenut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42803518/642706) is correct.

## `java.time.clock`

Java 9 and later includes an option with a resolution up to nanoseconds, in the new implementation of `Clock`.

## `Instant`

Access by calling `Instant`, a moment on timeline always in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

> instant().toString(): 2017-01-23T12:34:56.123456789Z

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of `Calendar.MILLISECOND`. Please see below for the difference based on the Java Docs.

Calendar.MILLISECOND:

> Field number for get and set indicating the millisecond within the
>   second. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the MILLISECOND is 250.

System.currentTimeMillis:

> Returns the current time in milliseconds. Note that while the unit of
>   time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the
>   value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger.
>   For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of
>   milliseconds. See the description of the class Date for a discussion
>   of slight discrepancies that may arise between "computer time" and
>   coordinated universal time (UTC).